# How to lock account on Spring Security 3.2.x?

Tags: spring-security

Before I decided to post this question. I looked into existing ones, but the code samples or references didn't help me to implement account locking on 3 invalid attempts.

I managed to count invalid login attempts by writing a custom **DaoAuthenticationProvider** and it counts only when the user exists.

Here's the code:

```
public class CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

private int i;
private String username;

@Autowired
UserService userService;

User user;

public CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider() {

    user = new User();
}

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

          try {

            return super.authenticate(authentication);

          } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {

             username = authentication.getName();

                if(userService.checkIfUserExists(username) == true) {

                    i++;
                    System.out.println("Failed login attempt #"+i+" for user: "+username);
                    user.setAttempts(i);

                    if(user.getAttempts() >=3) ; //LOCK THE ACCOUNT SOMEHOW
                }       
                throw e;        
          }              
    }
}
```

My entity class has implemented the UserDetails interface and one of the overridden methods is:

```
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {       
        return true;                     
    }
```

When I set the return value to FALSE I can't log in on any account using valid credentials.

Of course I tried to do some logic in this method to make it switch values from TRUE to FALSE when needed.

But nevertheless after 3 failed attempts when it's supposed to be set on FALSE it still "lets me in" when I use the correct password.

I saw in the previous version API documentation that there was before a default constructer with fields such as isAccountNonLocked, but in 3.2.x it's not present anymore and I don't know how to force the account lock.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: The user object is a field of your DAO, so as kaqqao says, you effectively only have one counter for your entire system.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple misunderstandings here. You need to keep a (preferably persistent) counter for each user separately (right now, all your users share the counter). For example, you should have two new DB columns, one to hold the failed attempts counter and the other to hold the last attempt timestamp for each user (I'm assuming you want temporary locking, otherwise you don't need the timestamp). Now, you will have to show what `UserDetailsService` you are using. This is where the DB is queried and actual [User](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) object (an implementation of `UserDetails`, can be your own) created, so that is where the lock flag on the object can and should be set, based on the values in the DB.

Comment: I have a column in my DB called accountNonLockex tinyint(1) set to default as 1 and attempts column. I'm using the standard UserDetailsService. I didn't write my own.

Comment: This means the scaffolding is ready. I'm guessing you need to subclass the User to implement your isAccountNonLocked logic, and JdbcDaoImpl to return this implementation. Make sure you update attempt counter field in the DB if Spring isn't handling this automatically.